# PHP caching image https request

Tags: php, header, http-caching

I have a very high I/O load on the server which causes 500 error many times per day while the CPU/RAM usage is basically non exsitent:

[image]

the main work of the server is serving images and videos. I'll focus the question on images and leave videos for another question.

This is the code for serving images:

```
$file = $_GET['n'];
$path = $root . '/memes/' . getDir($file) . '/' . $file;

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
header('Cache-control: max-age='.(60*60*24*365));
readfile($path);
```

I guess `header('Cache-control: max-age='.(60*60*24*365));` is for browser..

How can I cache the image into RAM and then serve it from there instead of putting the load on the SSD hunderts of times for the same image with PHP? I also need to set expire time, so if a specific image doesn't get requested for like 5 minutes it should be removed from the RAM / cache.

I want to make use of the CPU and RAM instead of letting them being almost useless :D

Comment: What does your `getDir` function do? Allowing a path to be specified directly from user input is highly dangerous, I hope you're sanitising that like mad inside getDir. P.S. People use stuff like redis for caching

Comment: As the name suggests it gets the dir of the image by the image name, it's doesn't request anything from the db or anything

Comment: So? Databases aren't the only vulnerable thing. The point is, malicious input could potentially misdirect the path and trick the script into fetching content you didn't intend, e.g. system files, code files, other sensitive information

Comment: This is getDir function: function getDir($inp){
    $inp = explode('/', $inp);
    $inp = $inp[count($inp) - 1];
    $inp = explode('.', $inp)[0];
    $inp = substr($inp, -2);
    return $inp;
} this could be dangerous? The user doesn't manually enter anything, the script does. But ofcourse it's easy to find out the url of the API so how to prevent stuff like that? The parent folder is "memes" which contains nothing sensitive so how can that be dangerous?

Comment: Well, do you know what `..` in a path string does?

Comment: But, I think your function more or less makes that part of it secure, just because it trims so much from the path, leaving only two characters left. BTW in PHP8 this code will break, you'll need to rename it to `getDir2` or something, or else it will clash with a built-in function of the same name.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the advice I'm really about to upgrade to PHP 8 :D Yeah .. will lead to previous dir but would it be able to pass through the parent "memes"?

Comment: However, including `$file` in there raw is _not_ safe. Imagine I put something like `?n=../../../var/www/html/yourfile.php` (or whatever would actually point to a real code file, relative to the memes directory) in the URL, that would be used as-is in your path, and so it would expose your PHP code, which could cause security issues. Or I could try to find an operating system file or something

Comment: Ok I will think about how to handle it differently, thanks again!